# Cross-browser word-break - doesn't work in Opera 12

Tags: css, opera, word-break

I have this css class for word-break in long texts without spaces.

```
    .wrapword{
        white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
        white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
        white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
        word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
        word-break: break-all;
        white-space: normal;
    }
```

Works for firefix 27, chrome 33, IE 10 and midori 0.43, but not for opera 12. 
Any suggestions. I am not a css ninja ...

Comment: It's not supported - [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/word-break)

Comment: After Opera 12, (starting with 13 and as today, version 19), Opera started to use Chrome engine to render the pages... until version 12, there was no support for several CSS rules.

Comment: Well, it does not work in Opera 12. What was the question? To get help with solving a problem, you should specify the problem. What is the actual content, and *how* should it be formatted?

Comment: @balexandre: There was no version 13, actually... Presto went to version 12, Blink started from version 15. See [the Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Opera_web_browser) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Opera 13 your CSS works, see http://caniuse.com/word-break. But there is no support for this rule in Opera 12.

The better solution would be hypenation. But this works even less via CSS, see http://caniuse.com/css-hyphens.

So my best guess: You may want to use Javascript like https://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/ to add hyphens to your text.

Comment: Thanks you. Just checked opera 19 on windows. ok there. Will check your JS suggestion. I am already using JS to check for vertical overflow and can add horizontial overflow check and add hyphens.

Comment: If hyphenation is a solution (it may well be a good solution to the original problem), then you should not be using `word-break` and `word-wrap` at all, since they b reak wo rds a rbitraril y ins tead of proper word division. In the rare cases where such breaking is OK, hyphenation would be wrong.